# Console Application uses in Real Life

Tags: vb.net, console-application

As part of our Programming Unit in college we are learning `Procedural Programming`. We are using Visual Basic and mostly doing console based applications.

After doing many different mini programs, It got me thinking **how would a Console Application be used in real life or in the real world?** In my opinion I don't even see myself using a console based application just because in this modern era nearly all programs/software is/are based on a Graphical User Interface.

So my questions to you guys, How would a Console Application be used in the real world? Why is there a need to create a command line interface based program? Are there any examples of great console applications out there?

Looking forward to the responses.

Thanks.

Comment: There many examples of console apps being used.  One common one is `ipconfig`.  Many apps that deal with networking will use the output from it to get things like ip addresses and gateway addresses, etc.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your definition of "real world/life". CLI apps/scripts tend to have less development overhead and are often far easier to be used by other apps/scripts.

Comment: Usually people write console apps for small tasks, that will not necesarily be an app that everyone will use. These apps usually are much faster than ones with GUI (less memory usage). As a programmer I find myself building a lot of small console apps, like something to do a search in disk, erase a bunch of files in a path, do something with images, etc...

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño, But surely if you were to erase a disk or a bunch of files you would do it via Windows? If it were me I would just go to the folder and delete all the files inside it. As for erasing a disk, Windows format tool, etc..

Comment: @Tahmid, maybe, but if it you needed an automatic way of doing it, and say you want to remove only certain type of files and you had thousands of files, would you still delete them manually? or write 5 lines of .net code that do all of that automatically for you, anytime you need it to.

Answer (score 6):

Console apps allow you to use words to control the computer.  You use it when:

- You don't need a graphical UI
- You want something easily automatable
- You want to interact with something using words.

They are also useful for starting in programming, as writing a GUI-based application can be fairly complex for your first program, even with WinForms.  It gets in the way of the true goal: teaching you how to think procedurally and how to program.

Examples of useful real-world console applications:

- `tfpt` is a console-only tool that provides additional features for TFS.
- The `git` console tool (for version control) has many, many more options and use cases than the GUI front-ends.
- I have written console programs that are executed by the windows Scheduled Programs dialog.  These run at a set time every day and perform a number of complex tasks.

Comment: i am writing a script which fetches the data from one database and inserts in to another database and that .vbs file is scheduled using windows task scheduler to run at specified timings,so can i say i have dealt with a kind of console application

Answer (score 3):

Console applications are very useful as tools. A clear advantage is that a console application can be integrated in batch scripts easily. 
Of course, the typical target audience of Console applications are technically savvy users.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember about console applications is that they have access to the console, directly. Assuming Linux, commands such as ntpdate, ftp, etc. are all very powerful and do **system level** operations without requiring a new, custom, program everytime you want to automate something.

I would say there are two situations to use console applications (scripts) over other approaches:

1.) In order to automate something (such as a system backup)

2.) You want to write a wrapper to automate sys-admin tasks (such as installing a bunch of programs on a newly imaged machine with a fresh operating system)

The key here is **automation**.